# Maven transitive dependency - Commons Collection version 3 vs 4

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons-collection

I have such configuration in `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

But unfortunately `mvn dependency:tree` shows me that `commons-beanutils` has dependency: commons-collections 3.x:

```
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
```

I don't want `Common Collection 3` in my code but it's possible that someone uses a class from this library by mistake (instead of `Common Collective 4`, which is preferred version).

As you see in dependency tree - I can't exclude the Common Collection 3, because it is used (can occur `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`).

Question:

**How to protect my code base against pollution of Commons Collection 3 API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dependency:analyze-only`

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html

to check whether you use undeclared dependencies, i.e. you use a transitive dependency without explicitly declaring it.

If you don't want this in your build, but just check it occasionally, you can use `dependency:analyze` from the command line.

Comment: But do you have any idea how to not only detect but also protect?

Comment: What do you mean by that? You can fail the build, is that not enough?

Comment: Ok. Failing the build is enough.